# Postgresql 15 - syntax sensitivity

Tags: postgresql

I've noticed that in older version of PG (example 13)
when I had query like:

```
select 1 where 1=1and 2=2
```

all was OK

but i try this in PG 15 I get error: trailing junk after numeric literal at or near "1a"

Have something changed or maybe there is a new option in configuration to make it more strict ?

Comment: To be honest, I am surprised that Postgres accepted that at all.

Comment: Weird !! Also `select 1 where 1=1or 2=2` is working on PG 13 and 14

Comment: [Posgres 13 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/heSJ6h8p)

Answer (score 11):

This was changed in v 15.0.

From the [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/15.0/):

> Prevent numeric literals from having non-numeric trailing characters (Peter Eisentraut)

> Previously, query text like 123abc would be interpreted as 123 followed by a separate token abc.

and similar

> Adjust JSON numeric literal processing to match the SQL/JSON-standard (Peter Eisentraut)

> This accepts numeric formats like .1 and 1., and disallows trailing junk after numeric literals, like 1.type().

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a fix in their query:

Make sure you signal that your query is a string.
E.g:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE col IN (12A2, 1E23)
```

does not work but

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE col IN ('12A2', '1E23')
```

does the job.

The problem above is solved by placing a space like so:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE 1=1 AND 2=2
```